# How to reference IE.document from another Sub in VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, object, reference

I am trying to read values from Internet Explorer and write them to Excel worksheet. To keep the code tidy, I would like to have certain parts of code in another procedure. I am struggling with referencing the IE.document.

Here is a simplified example of what I have functioning (ready state is ingnored in this example):

```
Sub OpenAndWriteIn()

        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "http://www.huffingtonpost.com"
        End With

        'Write in the Values to Sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("card__link")(0)
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("card__link")(1)

        MsgBox "Finished"
        IE.Quit

End Sub
```

This is something I would like to get, but it does not work:

```
Sub OpenIE()

        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE
            .navigate "http://www.huffingtonpost.com"
        End With

        'Based on the SearchedValue make a decision
        WriteIn IE
        IE.Quit

End Sub

Sub WriteIn(IE As Object)

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("card__link")(0)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("card__link")(1)

    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try with the one of the following definitions

```
Sub WriteIn(IE) or Sub WriteIn(IE as variant)
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the method `Sub WriteIn(IE As Object)` uses `ByRef` parameter. `ByRef` is default so when `ByRef/ByVal` was omitted then `ByRef` is used. In this case the declaration of `IE` variable in method `OpenIE()` must match the parameter declaration including the type. Simply the type must be consistent because the `ByRef` parameter references the argument.

So you can solve the problem either to declare both as either `Object` or `Variant` (but must not be mixed) or simply use `ByVal` in function `Sub WriteIn(ByVal IE As Object)`. With `ByVal` the parameter holds a value of the argument.